# python2 -m virtualenv env - error - no module named virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv

Following the instructions here https://github.com/oppia/oppia/wiki/Installing-Oppia-%28Mac-OS%29, I'm trying to get a virtualenv up and running on Mac. All goes well until I try to run `python2 -m virtualenv env`

At this point I get `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenv`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You missed `pip2 install virtualenv` — it's just one line above `python2 -m virtualenv env`.

Comment: Hi @phd, I followed each of the steps on the Wiki, but it seems to have problems - any other thoughts? Appreciate the response :)